# AppBar's foregroundColor property not working

Tags: flutter

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    foregroundColor: Colors.orange, // Has no impact
    leading: Icon(Icons.call),
    title: Text('AppBar'),
  ),
)
```

From docs:

> foregroundColor: The default color for Text and Icons within the app bar.

But none of my Text and icons in the app bar seems to have the orange color.

Comment: Which version of flutter are you using ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set `backwardsCompatibility` to `false` to let `foregroundColor` property to work. This is a new property which is `true` by default for now and once there's no longer a breaking change, it will be made `false` by default.

```dart
AppBar(
  foregroundColor: Colors.orange,
  backwardsCompatibility: false,
  title: Text('AppBar'),
)
```

Comment: In flutter 3.0+ it's already false by default, but `foregroundColor` doesn't work either... 

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way

```
 iconTheme: IconThemeData(
    color: Colors.orange
  ),
  title: const Text('Saved Suggestions', style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.orange
  )),
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
```

Comment: Hi, the question isn't about how to do that it rather is why the property isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

`AppBar` has no property `foregroundColor` (maybe removed). Use `textTheme` and `iconTheme` instead to change it's Text and Icons color

Comment: Thanks for your answer, may I know which version of Flutter you're using? I'm on `1.25.0-8.0.pre`

Comment: Am using the version `1.22.5-stable`

Comment: In the latest version, there's `foregroundColor` property. You can check the answer I left on this post.